# Background CSS NOT SHOWING behind wrapper

Tags: html, css, background-image, wrapper

I've tried the background-image tag in my CSS and also in a tag in my HTML.  I can't get anything to appear behind my wrapper. I can get my wrapper background to appear with color, but that it.

```html
html,
body {
    background-image: url("https://vgy.me/u/TpG24N");
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;

}

#wrapper {
    margin: 2% auto;
    width: 875px;
    height: 80%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: rgb(250, 194, 245)
}

#subwrapper {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML code, we don't know what your styles are referring to (divs, images, paragraphs?)

Comment: you have placed an image behind the wrapper, but the image url is incorrect. Define the image url with extension .jpg or .png etc.,

Answer (score 1):

You set a background-color in `#wrapper`, that will not show anything BEHIND it. Simply set:

```
#wrapper{
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

Now the element behind `#wrapper` will show through.

**Edit`:**

You can also make it `semi-transparent`, if you want, keeping your color and set `opacity` to a value between 0 and 1, like this:

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(250, 194, 245)
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Now the `#wrapper` will have a semi-transparent color. Experiment with the right value for opacity, until it looks like you want.

Comment: I changed this and corrected the URL and it works!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

your background image url `https://vgy.me/u/TpG24N` is not refer to an image, do you mean `https://vgy.me/TpG24N.jpg`

```
html,
body {
    background-image: url("https://vgy.me/TpG24N.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add image extension URL

```css
html,body {
    background-image: url("https://vgy.me/u/TpG24N");
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Also, Need to add

```css
#wrapper{
 background-color: transparent;
}
```